# How to execute a shell script from Docker file

Tags: bash, docker

Following is my shell script

```
#!/bin/bash
#shell script to execute the node js script 
echo "Hello World"
```

and here is my docker file. I want to execute this shell script from docker file. There are nodejs packages which I am installing which will be used later so ignore it for now.

```
FROM node:17.2.0
USER root
WORKDIR /LT
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install git --yes
COPY /LT .
COPY /LT/script.sh .   //this is the shell script . 
RUN bash script.sh
```

I don't get any error but the script does not get executed either which is Hello World is not printed.

What could be the solution?

Comment: Are you copying the bash file to the container? If not, how does the docker have access to the bash script?

Comment: And... if you ARE Copying it to the container, then it must be in one of those four `COPY` commands wherein the WORKDIR is `/LT` but when you run the script you are in WORKDIR `/LoadTesting` So either 1) You aren't copying the script in, or 2) You are copying it in, but it's not in your current WORKDIR.

Comment: Sorry. It was a copy paste error. I updated the script now. I am copying shell script to container and making sure that workdir is LT .

Comment: `copy /LT .` looks like you are trying to copy from a path outside the docker build context

Comment: What leads you to conclude the script isn't executing?  Can you reduce the example to a [mcve]; do you need to install that list of Node packages to demonstrate the issue, for example?

Comment: your script file names don't match between the COPY and the RUN

Answer (score -1):

```
RUN sh /LT/script.sh
```

finally this command worked for me. Thanks for all the suggestions

Comment: both bash and sh are available in node:17.2.0 and both should work. RUN command however is run during build and it's cached, so it would show some output only the first time you build your image. You are probably looking for CMD and/or ENTRYPOINT.